# Combination of reselect/connect from redux, aggrid and react hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, ag-grid

I'm refactoring one of the old React Components into React Hooks. Everything works fine except selector id that works randomly. Sometimes 'state' in selector is just a default one even though I know the state is valid. It seems like it is executed from a context that can't reach connected state so Ag Grid starts complaining that id can't be undefined.

```
import get from "lodash"
import { createSelector,createStructuredSelector } from "reselect"

const someotherselector = createSelector(...)
const idSelector = (state:State) => (row:any) => get(row, someotherselector(state)

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
getId: idSelector 
})

const WrappedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps,{})(Component)

const Component = props => {
// some stuff
// some hooks

  return <AgGrid getRowNodeId={props.getId}/>
}
```

Now if I create one more layer with class that overrides getRowNodeId with the same function it works perfectly fine. Example:

```
const WrappedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps,{})(Component1)

class Component1 extends React.Component
{
  render()
  {
    return <Component {...this.props} getRowNodeId={this.props.getRowNodeId}/>
  }
}

const Component = props => {
// some stuff
// some hooks

  return <AgGrid getRowNodeId={props.getId}/>
}
```

If it works fine with class component then I assume it's something with the context of a method that is being called, it seems like it isn't using the latest version of a state. Am I doing here something fundamentally wrong?

Edit: After looking further it seems like AgGrid never updates `getRowNodeId` handler, still uses the first one that received even though in Component new version was passed (it's a different function reference). Any idea why it is not picked up in the first example but is picked in the second one?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like AgGrid is not reassigning `getRowNodeId`handler so the only solution I see here is to set

```
const getRowNodeIdHandler = useRef(null);
getRowNodeIdHandler.current = getRowNodeId;
```

and then use `getRowNodeIdHandler` going forward. I don't have an idea though why it works with class components.